# How to make .svg transparent area NOT clickable

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to set an .svg image as a button. Only problem is that i'm able to click not only in the painted are, but the transparency aswell. This i need to disable so i can only click on the painted are.

Below i provide the html code i've got so far (basically what i copied from the actual file. To clarify, i exported this image from Adobe Illustrator on a windows machine.

I haven't made any modifications through .css yet.

```html
<div id="brand"><a href="index.html"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 106 106"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ff7800;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M67.78,52.28a5.58,5.58,0,0,0-6,0,6,6,0,0,0-2.11,2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0,7.42,6,6,0,0,0,2.11,2.45,5.58,5.58,0,0,0,6,0,6.05,6.05,0,0,0,2.11-2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0-7.42A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,67.78,52.28Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M53,0a53,53,0,1,0,53,53A53.06,53.06,0,0,0,53,0ZM77.67,78.67a10,10,0,0,1-4.3.91A13.53,13.53,0,0,1,69.14,79a12.7,12.7,0,0,1-3.74-2.09,34.09,34.09,0,0,1-4.26-4.15A13.74,13.74,0,0,1,55.34,70a14.09,14.09,0,0,1-3.91-5A15,15,0,0,1,50,58.44L50,45.66,43.86,55.92H39.69L33.61,46.1V58.44H25v-28h7.77L41.9,45.34,50.79,30.4h7.77L58.6,45a15.72,15.72,0,0,1,6.2-1.21,15.38,15.38,0,0,1,7.6,1.88,13.68,13.68,0,0,1,5.27,5.24,15,15,0,0,1,1.91,7.56A14.78,14.78,0,0,1,77.3,66.6a13.64,13.64,0,0,1-6.17,5.24,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.14.9,3.13,3.13,0,0,0,1.29.26,4.94,4.94,0,0,0,3.63-1.81L81,76A9,9,0,0,1,77.67,78.67Z"/></svg></a></div>
```

Comment: you need to add a click handler to the path and not the SVG

Answer (score 7):

You can move the `<a href="index.html">` into your SVG code, so that only the `<path>` elements are linked instead of the whole image:

```html
<div id="brand">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 106 106">
        <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ff7800;}</style></defs>
        <a href="index.html">
            <path class="cls-1" d="M67.78,52.28a5.58,5.58,0,0,0-6,0,6,6,0,0,0-2.11,2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0,7.42,6,6,0,0,0,2.11,2.45,5.58,5.58,0,0,0,6,0,6.05,6.05,0,0,0,2.11-2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0-7.42A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,67.78,52.28Z"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M53,0a53,53,0,1,0,53,53A53.06,53.06,0,0,0,53,0ZM77.67,78.67a10,10,0,0,1-4.3.91A13.53,13.53,0,0,1,69.14,79a12.7,12.7,0,0,1-3.74-2.09,34.09,34.09,0,0,1-4.26-4.15A13.74,13.74,0,0,1,55.34,70a14.09,14.09,0,0,1-3.91-5A15,15,0,0,1,50,58.44L50,45.66,43.86,55.92H39.69L33.61,46.1V58.44H25v-28h7.77L41.9,45.34,50.79,30.4h7.77L58.6,45a15.72,15.72,0,0,1,6.2-1.21,15.38,15.38,0,0,1,7.6,1.88,13.68,13.68,0,0,1,5.27,5.24,15,15,0,0,1,1.91,7.56A14.78,14.78,0,0,1,77.3,66.6a13.64,13.64,0,0,1-6.17,5.24,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.14.9,3.13,3.13,0,0,0,1.29.26,4.94,4.94,0,0,0,3.63-1.81L81,76A9,9,0,0,1,77.67,78.67Z"/>
        </a>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The ability to just use `<a href>` as-is inside an SVG image was a relatively recent introduction. If you need to support older browsers, you may need to include the `xlink` namespace:

```html
<div id="brand">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 106 106">
        <defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ff7800;}</style></defs>
        <a xlink:href="index.html">
            <path class="cls-1" d="M67.78,52.28a5.58,5.58,0,0,0-6,0,6,6,0,0,0-2.11,2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0,7.42,6,6,0,0,0,2.11,2.45,5.58,5.58,0,0,0,6,0,6.05,6.05,0,0,0,2.11-2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0-7.42A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,67.78,52.28Z"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M53,0a53,53,0,1,0,53,53A53.06,53.06,0,0,0,53,0ZM77.67,78.67a10,10,0,0,1-4.3.91A13.53,13.53,0,0,1,69.14,79a12.7,12.7,0,0,1-3.74-2.09,34.09,34.09,0,0,1-4.26-4.15A13.74,13.74,0,0,1,55.34,70a14.09,14.09,0,0,1-3.91-5A15,15,0,0,1,50,58.44L50,45.66,43.86,55.92H39.69L33.61,46.1V58.44H25v-28h7.77L41.9,45.34,50.79,30.4h7.77L58.6,45a15.72,15.72,0,0,1,6.2-1.21,15.38,15.38,0,0,1,7.6,1.88,13.68,13.68,0,0,1,5.27,5.24,15,15,0,0,1,1.91,7.56A14.78,14.78,0,0,1,77.3,66.6a13.64,13.64,0,0,1-6.17,5.24,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.14.9,3.13,3.13,0,0,0,1.29.26,4.94,4.94,0,0,0,3.63-1.81L81,76A9,9,0,0,1,77.67,78.67Z"/>
        </a>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Edit** I just tested this, it seems the most recent version of Safari on both iOS and OS X does *not* support the basic `href` version, they *only* support the `xlink:href` variant. With just `href` Safari on iOS will make the whole image clickable (which is what you're trying to avoid), on OS X the image will not be clickable at all.

Comment: Works like a charm, i'll change to "xlink:href". Thank you mate.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is a circle you can apply `border-radius: 50%` and `overflow: hidden` to the `a` element in this specific scenario.

```css
a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a svg {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 106 106">
        <defs>
            <style>.cls-1 {fill: #FF7800;}</style>
        </defs>
            
        <path class="cls-1" d="M67.78,52.28a5.58,5.58,0,0,0-6,0,6,6,0,0,0-2.11,2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0,7.42,6,6,0,0,0,2.11,2.45,5.58,5.58,0,0,0,6,0,6.05,6.05,0,0,0,2.11-2.45,9.11,9.11,0,0,0,0-7.42A6.05,6.05,0,0,0,67.78,52.28Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M53,0a53,53,0,1,0,53,53A53.06,53.06,0,0,0,53,0ZM77.67,78.67a10,10,0,0,1-4.3.91A13.53,13.53,0,0,1,69.14,79a12.7,12.7,0,0,1-3.74-2.09,34.09,34.09,0,0,1-4.26-4.15A13.74,13.74,0,0,1,55.34,70a14.09,14.09,0,0,1-3.91-5A15,15,0,0,1,50,58.44L50,45.66,43.86,55.92H39.69L33.61,46.1V58.44H25v-28h7.77L41.9,45.34,50.79,30.4h7.77L58.6,45a15.72,15.72,0,0,1,6.2-1.21,15.38,15.38,0,0,1,7.6,1.88,13.68,13.68,0,0,1,5.27,5.24,15,15,0,0,1,1.91,7.56A14.78,14.78,0,0,1,77.3,66.6a13.64,13.64,0,0,1-6.17,5.24,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.14.9,3.13,3.13,0,0,0,1.29.26,4.94,4.94,0,0,0,3.63-1.81L81,76A9,9,0,0,1,77.67,78.67Z"/>
    </svg>
</a>
```